# Closed subset with measure arbitrarily close to original set

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ be the measurable space formed by the real coordinate space of $n$ dimensions and the associated Borel algebra. We let $\mu$ be a measure for the space.

Let $S$ be an arbitrary measurable set. For any $\epsilon > 0$, is it true that there exists a $C \subseteq S$ such that

1) $C$ is closed

2) $\mu(S\setminus C) < \epsilon$

That is, does any set contains a closed subset with measure arbitrarily close to that of the original set?

It would seem to me that this is the case, and that we can find a union of intervals and singletons contained in $C$ such that (2) is satisfied. However, I have no idea how to prove this rigorously.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure

Comment: Thank you! I tried a google search but could only find results related to the closure of a set.


One issue though, is that a measure is inner-regular if it can be approximated by compacts from below. However, I just need it to be approximated by closed sets from below. Does this relax the assumptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in general. For a counterexample, take $\mu$ be the counting measure. However, if you add one more restriction on $\mu$ such that $\mu(K)<\infty$ for ever compact set $K$, then $\mu$ will have that property. In fact, with this additional restriction, $\mu$ is regular. 
See Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, theorem 2.18, page 48.

Comment: Why would the counting measure work (I assume you mean $\mu(X) = 1$ iff $X$ is uncountable)? If $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is uncountable and Borel then it contains a perfect set $K$ and then $\mu(K)= 1$.

Comment: I mean $\mu(E)=card(E)$, the number of elements in $E$.

Comment: But that doesn't map to real numbers?

Comment: The counting measure is inner regular, so we have the more limited $\mu(S) = \sup\{\mu(K) | \text{compact }  K \subseteq S \}$

Comment: As for theorem 2.18 of Rudin, it also requires the space to be a locally compact Hausdorff in which every open set is $\sigma$-compact, which is true for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Let the set $S$ be measurable with $\mu(S)<\infty$. Let $\mu_*$ denote the inner measure with respect to $\mu$. We have the following definition,

$$\mu_*(S):=\sup\{\mu(C): C\subset S, C\mbox{ compact}\}$$

Further, since the set $S$ is measurable w.r.t. $\mu$ we have $\mu(S)=\mu_*(S)$. Let $\epsilon>0$, if $\mu_*(S)=0$ then we are done so assume that $\mu_*(S)>0$. Then,

$$\sup\{\mu(C): C\subset S, C\mbox{ compact}\} >0\implies \exists C\subset S: \mu(S)-\epsilon<\mu(C)\leq\mu(S)\\
\implies \mu(C)<\mu(S)+\epsilon$$

Since $C$ is compact, it is also closed.

Comment: You should  maybe explain why $\mu_* (S) = \mu(S)$. This is not true in general.

Comment: Yeah I should have used the completed measure $\widehat{u}$

Comment: A set $S$ is called measurable if $\mu_*(S) = \mu^*(S) = \mu(S)$. So it is true in general.

Comment: @Meruda No, in your case "measurable" sets are just the Borel sets and if the measure is quite arbitrary then $\mu_* = \mu$ is not that clear.

Comment: I think the confusion is that the usual definition of "inner measure" $\mu_*$ and "outer measure" $\mu^*$ do not require $C$ to be compact, instead any countable union of measurable sets is enough.